# Run MySQL query inside a Laravel Blade template file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel blade file where there is a table and i had loaded data using my `web.php` file. Now I want to add a table column for the vehicle brand. For that I need to access the brand table's data and I need to print the corresponding column brand in the table following are the codes.

This is my `web.php`

```
 Route::get('/retailer/spares', function () {
    $models = DB::table('models')->get();
    $brands = DB::table('brands')->get();
    $spares = DB::table('spares')->get();

    return View::make('Retailer/spares')->with('models', $models)->with('brands', $brands)->with('spares', $spares);

});
```

This is my `spares.blade.php` please see the SQL query that had written. Other fields are working correctly.

```
<table  class="table ">

<tr>
    <th>Spare Id</th>
    <th>Part Number</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Brand</th>

    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Warranty</th>
    <th>Spare Image</th>

    <th>


        <input   type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search Spare">
    </th>

</tr>
<tbody id="tableModel">
<?php
foreach($spares as $spare){

?>
<tr>
    <td ><?php echo $spare->id;?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $spare->partNumber;?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $spare->description;?></td>

    <td>
        <?php

        $brand="SELECT brandName FROM brands WHERE id=' $spare->brand_id'";

        ?>
    </td>

    <td ><?php echo $spare->quantity;?></td>
    <td ><?php echo 'Rs.'. $spare->price;?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $spare->warranty;?></td>


    <td><div class="image"><?php echo ' <img  class="img-responsive"  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $spare->image ).'"/>';?></div></td>
    <td>

        <a class=" btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit" onclick="EditBrand('<?php echo $brand->brandName;?>','<?php echo $brand->id;?>')" >Edit </a>

        <a onclick="DeleteBrand(<?php echo $brand->id;?>)" style="" class=" btn btn-danger btn-sm"  >Delete </a>

    </td>

</tr>

<?php }?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Avoid this approach, its not recommended, by doing this you're not following MVC Pattern...

Comment: why you need to use this. This is not a MVC pattern.

Comment: ok could you please help me out here?

Comment: do you create Brand model?

Comment: yeah i had added it.

Comment: Do you create any ORM relationship between `Spare` & `Brand`?

Comment: What do you mean by ORM relationship. I think i havent created it.

Comment: Is it wrong to return the view as i had done in web.php or else runing a sql statement inside blade file? What doesnt follow the MVC pattern?\

Comment: Use models eloquent

Answer (score 3):

This is not good practice. You can join two table **spares and brands** in your controller. Try This.

```
$data = DB::table('brands')
            ->join('spares', 'brands.id', '=', 'spares.brand_id')
            ->select('brands.*', 'spares.id as spare_id', '',''....so on)
            ->get();
```

Here brands.* get all brands info you can manual get specific attribute from brands tabl as well as spares. You can get every info of brands and spares in $data array if Brands and spares has relationship